# Layer 2 MPLS VPN versus Layer 3 MPLS VPN

Tags: mpls, wan

A networking course that I follow briefly mentions Layer 2 and Layer 3 MPLS. I understand the difference between them.

However, the question is, are L2/L3 MPLS like two different services that we can purchase from our ISP?

If so, based on what would we choose, whether to use a L2 MPLS or L3 MPLS?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, the question is, are L2/L3 MPLS like two different services that we can purchase from our ISP?

Yes, exactly.

> If so, based on what would we choose, whether to use a L2 MPLS or L3 MPLS?

That depends on many factors.  Your network topology, the capabilities of the network equipment, traffic flows, redundancy, *etc*.  Every network is different and has different requirements.